# IIF returning duplicate values

Tags: sql, ms-access

The query below has the potential to produce duplicate values in the alias field. **Is there a way to tweak this query, so when a produced value (in this case |Bayer|) repeats, the output value only appears once in the AssociatedManufacturers field?** I understand that the table is not normalized, but I must work with the table I have.

Table:

| ClientID | Midol | Aleve | Tylenol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | Yes | Yes | No |

Query:

```
SELECT DrugsTaken.ClientId, IIf([Midol]="Yes", " |Bayer| ",Null) & IIf([Aleve]="Yes"," |Bayer| ",Null) & IIf([Tylenol]="Yes", " |J&J| ",Null)  AS AssociatedManufacturers
FROM DrugsTaken;
```

As written, the result of the query for ClientID 1 is: "|Bayer| |Bayer| |J&J|", but I'd like it to be "|Bayer| |J&J|".

Help with the query would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just check if `midol` is `'Yes'` **or** `aleve` is `'Yes'` in your first `iif()` and omit the last `iif()`.

Comment: You firstly should "unpivot" this table.

Comment: @Storax, yes, data structure is not normalized but OP already stated they have no choice and must work with table as is. A UNION query could 'unpivot' data but it is not necessary for achieving this output. Normalizing would actually make obtaining desired output more difficult.

Comment: _OP already stated they have no choice and must work with table as is_  This is usually an excuse for not wanting to re-consider his data structure resp. an xy-problem. Anyway, if OP wants to go this direction ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if Midol OR Aleve = Yes.

```
IIf([Midol]="Yes" Or [Aleve]="Yes"," |Bayer| ",Null) & IIf([Tylenol]="Yes", " |J&J| ",Null)
```